# Bootstrap button group and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

In my Rails app I'd like to use a Bootstrap button group. There is a single field, and each button represents a different state .. ie like radio buttons.

Even better if I can do it with simple_form but can't find a solution by Googling.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user_word, url: user_words_path, remote: true, wrapper: :inline_form, html: { class: 'form-inline' } do |f| %> 
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="selector" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" >
              <button class="btn level-unknown" id='unknown' type="button">Unknown</button>
              <button class="btn level-low" id='low' type="button">Low</button>
              <button class="btn level-medium active" id='medium' type="button">Medium</button>
              <button class="btn level-high" id='high' type="button">High</button>
              <button class="btn level-known" id='known' type="button">Known</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: You should post the code/form you're trying to apply this to as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're asking.  If your issue is that the active class is not switching to your clicked button, it's because you need javascript to do so.

```
$('#selector button').on('click',
function(e){
    var $obj=$(e.target);
        $('#selector .active').removeClass('active'); //remove active class from buttons
    $obj.addClass('active'); //add active class to clicked button
});
```

See a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14519/

**Edit:**

I just learned that this functionality is built in to the bootstrap javascript library.  Your markup just needs to be modified to match this syntax

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
```

See example at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: That's 90% there, but how do I submit to a Rails form?

Comment: Hi @ardochhigh, did you ever figure this one out? Running into a similar issue, need to tie the button selection so its passed in with the rest of the form params...